# Redirect to alias in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, routes

Hi I need to redirect to alias in url with codeigniter... for example 
If the user type in the browser http://www.website.com/fedex, need to get the fedex like alias and find in the database by this alias and redirect to the correct url that must be http://www.website.com/pages/fedex... here is my code...

PD: By the way do not exists controller named fedex.

.. routes.php ...

```
$route['default_controller'] = "alias";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route[':any'] = "alias/index/$1";
```

.. pages Controler ..

```
class Alias extends CI_Controller 
{
   public function __construct()
   {
      parent::__construct();
   }

   public function index()
   {
      $alias = $this->uri->segment(1);
      echo "Alias:" . $alias;
   }
}
```

Comment: What are you explaining sounds like you want /name to redirect to /pages/name is that right? What is the database lookup doing?

Comment: I was looking in database if the name exists as username.. but the important thing is make the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do...

```
class Alias extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct()
  {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->database();
      $this->load->helper('url');
  }

  public function index(){
      echo 'Default page!';
  }

  public function get($alias)
  {
      $this->db->from('users')->where(array('username' => $alias));
      $query = $this->db->get();
      if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        //This means that a row was returned from the database and their is a user that exists with that name
        redirect("/pages/$alias");
      }
      else{
        echo 'There is no user that exists with that username';
      }
  }

  public function pages($alias){
      echo "Hey $alias!";
  }

}


//Routes
$route['default_controller'] = "alias";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['pages/:any'] = "alias/pages/$1";
$route[':any'] = "alias/get/$1";
```

In the constructor it loads the database class and the URL helper. In the index() method is uses the database to select a row from the "users" table where their username is the $alias. Then it checks with an if statement if a row was returned from the database. If a row was returned that means a user exits and to redirect to /pages/username. Else it will echo saying no one exits with that username.

Make sure to change the database info match your database setup as well as make sure $active_record is set to TRUE in the database config file.

Comment: Yes but the problem is when I type for example http://www.website.com/pages/fedex I get Page Not Found.

Comment: I added more methods and added the routes at the bottom to use. Let me know how this works

Comment: look the url is http://localhost/biipit/ ... here I get 'Default Page' but when I type http://localhost/biipit/fedex .. I get Page Not Found.

Comment: what is supposed to happen when you go to localhost/biipit/fedex? Did the route I added now fix that?

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /biipit/fedex was not found on this server.

Comment: In your example with the word "biipit" and/or "fedex" be subject to change. For example do you want /cat/dog to go the the same page as /biitpit/fedex just with different content? Are one of both of the segments in the URI variable is what I am asking.

Comment: biipit is the root folder in my localhost... by the way here is the code of the .htaccess
    RewriteEngine on
    #RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Are you using MAMP or WAMP or something like that?

Comment: may this help... http://localhost/biipit/alias/pages/fedex and I get Page Not Found too

Comment: look I make some changes... and http://localhost/biipit/fedex is redirected to the localhost page... and by your comments must be redirected to alias/get/$1 ... now what is the problem... please help ASAP.